# Не работает скрипт .cmd

Tags: cmd, bat

Мне необходимо узнать какой сегодня день недели и если четверг, то выдать "Нужен ли дополнительный акцепт".

```
@echo off
For /F "Tokens=%$DayOfWeek% Delims=," %%i In ("Воскресенье,Понедельник,Вторник,Среда,Четверг,Пятница,Суббота") Do Set $DayOfWeekName=%%i 
Echo %$DayOfWeekName% > tmp.txt

If Exist tmp.txt (
  For /F "Delims=" %%I In (tmp.txt) Do Set BmpPath=%%~I
)


if %BmpPath%=="Четверг" ( set /p var="Нужен дополнительный акцепт, продолжить установку?" ) else ( Echo Сегодня: %BmpPath% )
```

Comment: а если .bat?
Можно еще echo off убрать и посмотреть на какой команде падает

Comment: @Gelloiss Сам скрипт не работает определенным образом, ошибка как я понимаю где то либо в типе данных либо где то еще, то есть когда я явным образом объявляю переменную BmpPath, то скрипт работает правильно и if else срабатывает, а когда я меняю дату, то скрипт перестает работать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот рабочий скрипт:

```
@echo off
chcp 65001
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cls

::создание мини-скрипта для вычисления дня недели
echo WScript.Echo^(new Date^(^).getDay^(^)^) > %TEMP%\tmp.js

::запуск мини-скрипта и получение номера дня недели
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`cscript /nologo %TEMP%\tmp.js`) do (
    set "Day=%%i"
)

if %Day% equ 4 (
    ::четверг
    set /p "var=Нужен дополнительный акцепт, продолжить установку?"
) else (
    ::не четверг - вычисления дня недели на основе его номера
    if %Day% equ 0 (
        echo Сегодня воскресенье.
    ) else if %Day% equ 1 (
        echo Сегодня понедельник.
    ) else if %Day% equ 2 (
        echo Сегодня вторник.
    ) else if %Day% equ 3 (
        echo Сегодня среда.
    ) else if %Day% equ 4 (
        echo Сегодня четверг.
    ) else if %Day% equ 5 (
        echo Сегодня пятница.
    ) else if %Day% equ 6 (
        echo Сегодня суббота.
    )
)

pause > nul
```